# Wrong answer in Normal Distribution in C

Tags: c, matlab

I have applied the normal distribution function using the equation given in this link:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution

I made this code for normal distribution

```
float m=2.0;
float s=0.5;
float x[3]={1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
float xs[3];
const float pi = 3.141;

for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    xs[i]=(1/s*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-(pow(x[i]-m,2)/2*pow(s,2)));
    printf("\n%f",xs[i]);
}
```

The answer for this code is 4.42, 5.01, 4.42

and I have the same code in Matlab

```
x_s_new=[1 2 3];
x_s=2+0.5.*randn(1,9);
x_s=x_s_new+0.5.*randn(1,3);
plot(x_s_new)
```

but the answers in matlab is 0.8 , 1.9 , 3.7

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

I want to apply normal distribution using C

Thanks :)

Comment: pi approximation could be better....Use value in math.h

Comment: `randn` is not the CDF or PDF for the normal distribution, its a random number generator! Check `normpdf` and `normcdf`

Comment: Before starting to convert the code. you should clean up your matlab code. What is the purpose of `x_s=2+0.5.*randn(1,9);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Matlab code is not the analogue of your C code. The C code computes the value of the probability density function of the normal distribution at certain points. The Matlab code generates random numbers from the normal distribution.

The Matlab code corresponding to the C code is

```
m = 2;
s = 0.5;
x = [1 2 3];

for i = 1 : 3
    xs(i) = (1/s*sqrt(2*pi)) * exp(-( (x(i)-m)^2/2*s^2));
    fprintf('%f\n',xs(i));
end
```

and gives the same result

```
4.424183
5.013257
4.424183
```

However, there's a mistake because `/` in Matlab and C only applies to the immediate next operand. Correctly it would be

```
xs(i) = 1/(s*sqrt(2*pi)) * exp(-( (x(i)-m)^2/(2*s^2)));
```

and correspondingly in C.

To translate the code using `randn` to C – to my knowledge there is no standard function in C to generate normally distributed random numbers, you need to find a library that includes such a function, or build it yourself starting from `random()`.

Comment: Any idea to implement this code in C that it produces the same result as of Matlab because I want to convert this matlab code to C .

Comment: @user2828488: Do you really need the exact same random process? This would require to get the C-Code of the matlab random generator (which is available), set the same seeds, implement randn the same way TMW did.

Comment: Yes I want the same random process as I need to convert the matlab code to C and C doesnot support the randn function.

Can you share that method here ?

Comment: check `edit rand` for informations about the random number generator matlab uses.

Comment: I think you are talking about this 'r = a + (b-a).*rand(100,1);'

Comment: @user2828488: Daniel R. means to type "edit rand" into Matlab, to see how it is implemented. However, both `rand` and `randn` are built-in functions.

Comment: @ Daniel R: I have checked the edit rand it's showing the method for uniform distribution , not the normal distribution or guassian distribution as in randn

Comment: @user2828488: The easiest way will be to compile `randn` to C using [`codegen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ref/codegen.html). Otherwise you'll need to implement [Mersenne twister](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html) and some form of transform from uniform to normal random numbers ([log-polar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marsaglia_polar_method) is simplest, but Matlab uses a version of the faster [Ziggurat algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziggurat_algorithm)). If you have issues, with either of these, they'd really be separate questions.